# Тяжелые и легкие компоненты в Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Как можно лаконично и емко дать ответ на вопрос, что такое легкие и тяжелые компоненты, в чем их различия, плюсы и минусы?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Если очень коротко, то:

1. Тяжелые компоненты - это компоненты, которые имеют платформенно-зависимую реализацию.
2. Легкие компоненты - это компоненты, полностью написанные на `Java` и не зависящие от `peer-интерфейсов`.

---

**Пояснение**

Приложения `Java` должны работать в любой, или хотя бы во многих графических средах. В связи с этим, требуется библиотека классов, независимая от конкретной графической системы, поэтому в `JDK` задачу решили следующим образом: были разработаны интерфейсы (также называются `peer-интерфейсами`), содержащие методы работы с графическими объектами. Классы библиотеки `AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit)` реализуют эти интерфейсы для создания приложений. Приложения `Java` используют данные методы для размещения и перемещения графических объектов, изменения их размеров, взаимодействия объектов.

Для работы с экраном в конкретной графической среде эти интерфейсы реализуются отдельно для каждой. В каждой графической среде это делается по-своему: средствами этой оболочки (с помощью графических библиотек данной операционной системы).

При выводе объекта, созданного в приложении `Java` и основанного на `peer-интерфейсе`, на экране создается парный ему (`peer-to-peer`) объект графической подсистемы операционной системы, который и отображается на экране. Эти объекты тесно взаимодействуют во время работы приложения. Поэтому графические объекты `AWT` в каждой графической среде имеют вид, характерный для этой среды и выглядят как "родные" окна.

Начиная с версии `JDK 1.1` библиотека `AWT` была переработана. В нее добавлена возможность создания компонентов, полностью написанных на `Java` и не зависящих от `peer-интерфейсов`. Такие компоненты стали называть `"легкими" (lightweight)` в отличие от компонентов, реализованных через `peer-интерфейсы`, названных `"тяжелыми" (heavy)`.

`"Легкие" компоненты` везде выглядят одинаково, сохраняют заданный при создании вид (`look and feel`). Более того, приложение можно разработать таким образом, чтобы после его запуска можно было выбрать какой-то определенный вид: Motif, Metal, Windows 95 или какой-нибудь другой, и сменить этот вид в любой момент работы. Эта интересная особенность `"легких" компонентов` получила название `PL&F (Pluggable Look and Feel)` или `plaf`.

Была создана обширная библиотека `"легких" компонентов Java`, названная `Swing`. В ней были переписаны все компоненты библиотеки `AWT`, так что библиотека `Swing` может использоваться самостоятельно, несмотря на то, что все классы из нее расширяют классы библиотеки `AWT`.

В данный момент `Swing` является основной библиотекой пользовательского интерфейса в `Java`, `AWT` - не дорабатывается. Использование библиотеки `Swing` - почти всегда предпочтительнее чем `AWT`, за исключением тех случаев, когда нужна обратная совместимость с `Java 1`.